# what happen if child and parent process read from the stdin at the same time?

Tags: c, linux, fork, stdin

what happen if child and parent process read from the stdin at the same time?

```
int main(void){
int pid;
char    str[6];

str[5] = 0;
pid = fork();
if (pid)
{
    read(0, str, 5);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
}
else
{
    read(0, str, 5);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

as I expected, i will type the keyboard two times, hit enter twice, and it will show two results that I typed. But it didn't!
so exactly what happened when two process request stdin at the same time??

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having a concrete example, I'll assume you typed `foo⏎bar⏎`. TTYs are line-buffered by default, so neither process will receive anything until you hit the Enter key the first time. Once you do, one of the processes (it's completely arbitrary whether it's the parent or the child, and may not even be the same across executions of the same binary on the same system) will get `"foo\n"` in its copy of `str`, and the return value of `read` will be 4. Once you hit the Enter key the second time, the other process will get `"bar\n"` in its copy of `str`, and its return value of `read` will also be 4. In this case, the two halves will be printed in the order you typed them in.

If you saw something different, it's probably because you typed more than 5 characters, including the Enter key. Again, for the sake of having a concrete example, assume you typed `foobar⏎`. Now, when you hit Enter, one of the processes will get `"fooba"` in `str` and have `read` return 5, and the other one will get `"r\n"` in `str` and have `read` return 2. In this case, the two halves could get printed in either order.

Also, by only setting the last element of `str` to 0, and then ignoring the return value of `read`, you risk printing garbage characters any time it reads less than 4 bytes.